# Copying a path of the app to a new directory?

Tags: applescript, copy-paste, path

I was wondering if someone could help me make an AppleScript that copies the app the script is into another location. So, this is what I tried... (Please don't say anything since I am new at Applescript)

```
set Folder to "~/Public/"
set FdrPosix to quoted form of POSIX path of Folder
set newFolderName to "Folder"
set destinationFdrPosix to quoted form of FdrPosix & POSIX file newFolderName
set sourceFilename to path to me
set sourceFnPosix to quoted form of FdrPosix & POSIX file sourceFilename
tell application "Finder"
  make new folder at alias FdrPosix with properties {name:newFolderName}
  copy file sourceFnPosix to folder destinationFdrPosix
end tell
```

Comment: I would ask what is the overall thing you are trying to achieve - copying the app itself seems a bit odd

Comment: @Mark Well, I'm doing a project for my school where they want me to create an Applescript to copy an app into a certain folder... I'm not quite sure what it's for, but that's what happens when you join the school's tech club...